# Untrack and delete from git without deleting other contributors files

Tags: git

Currently if there is a file/folder that has been tracked in a git repository (such as IDE settings) I use `git rm --cached -r <file-folder-regex>` to remove them from git but keep the files locally.

However, once I push that change and it is pulled by others, their IDE settings will be deleted as well.

Is there a different way to make git forget about tracking a file/folder without it deleting for others on the project and letting them keep whatever their current state is?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Don't keep user specific config in a shared git repo. Instead keep an example config and ignore the actual config. This means a user can change the config without worrying about affecting others.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah, that's ideal. Though accidental commits happen.

Comment: Ask them to backup before pulling.